# How do I change the scan depth for page template files?

Tags: themes, page-template

I want to move my template files to a file sub-directory like `./tpl/page` but it seems to only scan one directory deep.  Is there a way in my theme that I can set it to scan deeper?

Comment: What templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Unortunatly 1 directory depth is hardcoded as second argument for `get_files` method in method  `WP_Theme -> get_page_templates`.